# Wiring Multiple Outlets, Switches Lights

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

I'm adding in a few switches and outlets to a garage and I'm wondering how to wire them in. One outlet I want to be switched. Both outlets are GFCI as they are in a garage. I'm using 14/2 wire. I've attached a picture that shows the path I'd like to take for the wire from one device to the others from left to right.

Thanks

[image: Wiring]

Comment: Is the switched receptacle going to be on a ceiling?  Do you believe a GFCI  is just a kind of receptacle, and is so, how attached are you to that belief?

Comment: Do you already have a 20A circuit serving that garage?

Answer (score 1):

Make the first switch box double gang, and add a GFCI receptical there.
Both incoming conductors should enter that GFCI outlet first, and that first GFCI outlet will provide GFCI protection for the whole addition in a conveniently accessible location.

On the 'load side' of that GFCI, branch off to the switch in the same box, and to the right.  GFCI outlet's usually have lugs that can accommodate two outgoing load conductors.  If not, use a wire nut.

From the switch go up to a normal outlet on the ceiling (if that's what your diagram intended).

From the wire nut (or the GFCI's second conductor), head right to the second box, and use a wire nut there to branch to the switch in that box and the unswitched outlet further right

connect the light to the switch in the second box.

Done.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1, GFCI protect the whole kaboodle

[image]

Option 2, 2 separate GFCIs and the middle lamp is not on GFCI

[image],